# Select all rows from where a condition is true in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe

```
 Id  Seqno. Event
 1     2    A 
 1     3    B 
 1     5    A 
 1     6    A 
 1     7    D
 2     0    E
 2     1    A 
 2     2    B 
 2     4    A 
 2     6    B
```

I want to get all the events happened since the count of recent occurrence of Pattern A = 2 for each ID.  Seqno. is a sequence number for each ID.
The output will be

```
 Id  Seqno. Event 
 1     5    A 
 1     6    A 
 1     7    D
 2     1    A 
 2     2    B 
 2     4    A 
 2     6    B
```

so far i tried,

```
  y=x.groupby('Id').apply( lambda 
  x:x.eventtype.eq('A').cumsum().tail(2)).reset_index()
  p=y.groupby('Id').apply(lambda x:       
  x.iloc[0]).reset_index(drop=True)
  q= x.reset_index()
  s= pd.merge(q,p,on='Id')
  dd= s[s['index']>=s['level_1']]
```

I was wondering if there is a good way of doing it.

Comment: Shouldn't group 2 only include the last 2 rows? Since we are looking for the rows with the second occurrence of A onwards.... correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks @coldspeed. Actually, for each group we are counting A from the last or most recent event. As soon as our count equals to 2 we will return all the rows( including the one with second occurrence) until the end(most recent) event  of that group.

Comment: The logic still doesn't make sense. For Id 2, you are including row with seq no 1 where count of A is still 1.

Comment: Yes, @Vaishali, exactly. Still does not make sense to me, OP.

Comment: It's second occurrence counting from the bottom of the group up, then returning everything below

Comment: My apologies guys, I will try to explain in a better way...For each group I am counting them from the last/(most recent event) of this group. For id 1 , the 4th  row is count 1 and 3rd row is count 2.  Hence, it will return 3rd, 4th and 5th row..Similarly for id 2, let's count from the bottom/last/most recent event of group 2, 10th row  has no B so count =0. 9th row = count 1, 8th row again has no B so count will still be 1, 7th row has A so count = 2. Hence i will return, 7th, 8th, 9th and 10th row...Pleas let me know if i need to explain more. Thanks

Comment: @ALollz exactly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby` with `cumsum`, subtract it from the count of A's per group, and filter:

```
g = df['Event'].eq('A').groupby(df['Id'])
df[(g.transform('sum') - g.cumsum()).le(1)]

   Id  Seqno. Event
2   1       5     A
3   1       6     A
4   1       7     D
6   2       1     A
7   2       2     B
8   2       4     A
9   2       6     B
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to cold ,ALollz and Vaishali, via the explanation (from the comment) using `groupby` with `cumcount` get the count , then we using `reindex` and `ffill`

```
s=df.loc[df.Event=='A'].groupby('Id').cumcount(ascending=False).add(1).reindex(df.index)
s.groupby(df['Id']).ffill()
Out[57]: 
0    3.0
1    3.0
2    2.0
3    1.0
4    1.0
5    NaN
6    2.0
7    2.0
8    1.0
9    1.0
dtype: float64
yourdf=df[s.groupby(df['Id']).ffill()<=2]
yourdf
Out[58]: 
   Id  Seqno. Event
2   1       5     A
3   1       6     A
4   1       7     D
6   2       1     A
7   2       2     B
8   2       4     A
9   2       6     B
```